# How to see output of print statements when scrapy logger enabled

Tags: python, logging, scrapy, stdout, stderr

For debug purposes I need to see both output of log messages and print statements when working with Scrapy. Hovewer, when I start Scrapy logger, I no longer see output of print statements! How should I modify the following sample code to see both print statements?

```
from scrapy import log

print 'PRINT OUTPUT BEFORE'
log.start(loglevel='DEBUG',logstdout=True)
print 'PRINT OUTPUT AFTER'
```

Output:

```
PRINT OUTPUT BEFORE
```

I beleive redirecting stderr or stdout may solve the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`logstdout` must be set to False to disable stdout from being redirected.

```
from scrapy import log

print 'PRINT OUTPUT BEFORE'
log.start(loglevel='DEBUG', logstdout=False)
print 'PRINT OUTPUT AFTER'
```

With output:

```
PRINT OUTPUT BEFORE
PRINT OUTPUT AFTER
```

Comment: `scrapy.log` has been deprecated alongside its functions in favor of explicit calls to the Python standard `logging`. See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html

Answer (score 4):

I think above works for old version. They seems to have deprecated scrapy.log .
Refer:
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html

Eg:

```
import logging

logging.warning("This is a warning")
logging.info("This is an info")
logging.error("This is an error")
```

As my config was set to warn. I got only below

```
WARNING:root:This is a warning
ERROR:root:This is an error
```

Note that this is helpful if you are using scrapyd. As scrapy crawl  will print all but scrapyd doesn't do same way.